# Transform users (repeated over multiple rows) and items in a dataframe into a label binarized dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 1], 
    ['b', 1],
    ['c', 1],
    ['a', 2], 
    ['c', 3], 
    ['b', 4], 
    ['c', 4]
], columns=['item', 'user'])
```

Where each user is repeated across multiple rows (with different items).

I would like to perform a LabelEncoder/LabelBinarizer like transform (??) to convert the DataFrame into something that looks like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 1, 1], #user 1
    [1, 0, 0], #user 2
    [0, 0, 1], #user 3
    [0, 1, 1]  #user 4
], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I likely don't want to use pandas (`pivot`, `get_dummies`, `crosstab`), because I want to pass a new user to the transformer:

```py
new_user = pd.DataFrame([
    ['c', 5], 
    ['d', 5]
], columns=['item', 'user'])
```

And get back something like this:

```py
[0, 0, 1]
```

**Important**: solution must solve for the new user case (and dropped 'd' item), and preserve column order as well as dimensions

Comment: Can you define the list of items beforehand?

Comment: @DanielMesejo sure! I'm imagining a `fit()` step that will memorize a list of all the possible items (sort of like LabelEncoder)

Comment: @emehex Check out my answer. Fixed few more errors. Sorry jupyer using previous variables. Found bugs after restarting. BTW good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with some standard scikit-learn:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def squish(df, user='user', item='item'):
    df = df.groupby([user])[item].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
    X = pd.DataFrame(df)[item]
    return X

cv = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(','))
X = squish(df)
cv.fit_transform(X).todense()
```

Which will produce:

```
# matrix([[1, 1, 1],
#         [1, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

It also solves for the new user case:

```
new_user = pd.DataFrame([
    ['c', 5],
    ['d', 5]
], columns=['item', 'user'])

X_new = squish(new_user)
cv.transform(X_new).todense()
```

Correctly yielding:

```
# matrix([[0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

- Oh boy. Here is what i came up with.
- Long Chaining. I will break it down.

```py
import pandas as pd
def encode(l):
    return pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['item', 'user'])['item'].unique()

# create dataframe
# group by and get dummies
# remove unncessary colums which are not part of encoding class
# apply to create list
def add_user(l, _key_):
    return  pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['item', 'user']).\
            groupby('user')['item'].apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies().\
            reindex(columns=_key_).fillna(0).astype('int').\
            apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)

_key_ = encode ([
    ['a', 1], 
    ['b', 1],
    ['c', 1],
    ['a', 2], 
    ['c', 3], 
    ['b', 4], 
    ['c', 4]
])
```

```
add_user([
    ['a', 1], 
    ['b', 1],
    ['c', 1],
    ['a', 2], 
    ['c', 3], 
    ['b', 4], 
    ['c', 4]
], _key_)
```

**Output:**

```
user
1    [1, 1, 1]
2    [1, 0, 0]
3    [0, 0, 1]
4    [0, 1, 1]
```

```
add_user([['b',5],['d', 5]], _key_)
```

**Output:**

```
user
5    [0, 1, 0]
```

- `encode` will generate initial `keys` for your encoder.
- `add_user` you can call this function for each new user.
- Note you can `reset_index` to get `user` column.

**Soulution 2:**

- inspired from @WeNYoBen's Answer.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 1], 
    ['b', 1],
    ['c', 1],
    ['a', 2], 
    ['c', 3], 
    ['b', 4], 
    ['c', 4]
], columns=['item', 'user'])
_key_ = df.item.unique()
def add_user(l, _key_):
    df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['item','user'])
    return pd.crosstab(df.user, df.item).reindex(columns=_key_.tolist()).fillna(0).astype('int').apply(list, axis=1)

add_user([['b',5],['d', 5]], _key_)
```

- Not readable version of `add_user` function.

```py
def add_user(l, _key_):
    return pd.crosstab(*[[list(x)] for x in list(zip(*l))[::-1]]).reindex(columns=_key_.tolist()).fillna(0).astype('int').apply(list, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey @Poojan, thanks for your work! I've been mulling over the problem a bunch more and just posted the solution I landed on. Might perhaps be of some interest!

Comment: @emehex That's a good solution. But since you didn't mention the use of sklearn i provided on with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I would create a class `Encoder`, like the following:

```
class Encoder:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = None

    def transform(self, lst):
        """Returns a dictionary where the keys are the users_ids and the values are the encoded items"""
        if self.items is None:
            self.items = self.__items(lst)

        users = {}
        for item, user in lst:
            users.setdefault(user, set()).add(item)

        return {user: np.array([item in basket for item in self.items], dtype=np.uint8) for user, basket in users.items()}

    def reset(self):
        self.items = None

    @staticmethod
    def __items(lst):
        seen = set()
        items = []
        for item, _ in lst:
            if item not in seen:
                items.append(item)
                seen.add(item)
        return items
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
encoder = Encoder()
result = encoder.transform(df.values.tolist())  # here df is your original DataFrame
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data=result.values(), columns=encoder.items, index=result.keys())
print(df_result)
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  1  1
```

Notice that the index in the `df_result` are the users. Then the new case could be handled like this:

```
new_user = pd.DataFrame([
    ['c', 5],
    ['d', 5]
], columns=['item', 'user'])
new_user_result = encoder.transform(new_user.values.tolist())
print(pd.DataFrame(data=new_user_result.values(), columns=encoder.items, index=new_user_result.keys()))
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c
5  0  0  1
```

Receiving a list and returning a dictionary is a more flexible approach, at least in my opinion. Also returning a dictionary will handle the case were the users are not consecutive integers (they can be UUIDs, for example). Finally in the `Encoder` class, you also has a reset method, essentially to *forget* the items.

Comment: Hey @Daniel Mesejo, I've been mulling over the problem a bunch more and just posted the solution I landed on. Might be of some interest!